# How to plot an area under an integral in a function? Argument Polygon is giving an error for arguments

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate an integral, plot it then highlights the area below it. I managed to find some code that uses the Polygon function, that is giving me an error.

Below I provide some of the code.

```
a = 0.5 # left integration limit 
b = 9.5  # right integration limit
Ix = np.linspace(a, b)  
Iy = f(Ix) # Integration function values

verts = [(a, 0)] + list(zip(Ix, Iy)) + [(b, 0)]
poly = Polygon(verts, facecolor='0.7', edgecolor='0.5')
```

the code is giving me the following error,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-0113439d2980> in <module>()
      5 
      6 verts = [(a, 0)] + list(zip(Ix, Iy)) + [(b, 0)]
----> 7 poly = Polygon(verts, facecolor='0.7', edgecolor='0.5')

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'facecolor'
```

I have tried to look at the shapely user manual https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html but could not figure out a solution.

I also found similar errors but this was regarding matplotlib.

Sorry if this is a simple question, I am new to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there is a confusion here between two library.
You try to use Shapely but this library has no "facecolor" argument for its Polygon's class :

see this part of the documentation :

https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#polygons

Maybe you used the cartopy library before, which has this facecolor argument :

https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.14/matplotlib/feature_interface.html

so you should remove this argument :

```
a = 0.5 # left integration limit 
b = 9.5  # right integration limit
Ix = np.linspace(a, b)  
Iy = f(Ix) # Integration function values

verts = [(a, 0)] + list(zip(Ix, Iy)) + [(b, 0)]
poly = Polygon(verts)
```

Or use cartopy library.

**From the question's author comment **  :

Indeed the import must change from Shapely Library to "from matplotlib.patches import Polygon".

Comment: Oh sorry from further research I have found the issue. Thank you

Comment: "from matplotlib.patches import Polygon" solves the issue, it is not Polygon from Shapely but from matplotlib.patches.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was solved by using,

```
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
```

The error that I had made is confusing the `Polygon` in `matplotlib.patches`  with `Polygon` in shapely that is shown below.

```
>>> from shapely.geometry import Polygon
>>> polygon = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)])
>>> polygon.area
0.5
>>> polygon.length
3.4142135623730949
```